# Binary Search on a number as well as a quote?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For one of my classes I have to use binary search to first look to see if the quote exists (by looking for the quote number) and if it does then print the quote out. In the text file, each quote has two lines.

The first line contains the quotes number, and the second line is the quote. The quote numbers are already sorted for the program.

The requirements for the program are as followed: Create a program that reads the quotes into an array. (Done) The user will then request a the title based on the number they enter. (Done) Your program then uses binary search to find the quote if it exists. I currently have a majority of it but it seems to not be working. I read from an arraylist to an array but I'm clueless what to do after this. I've been stuck on this problem for a while and any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: **The existing code just reads it into an array. What i'm trying to do is look to see if the number exists and if it does then print out the quote underneath it from the text file. If it doesn't exist then print out it doesn't exist. **

The program should roughly be looking like this. [image]

My code so far:

```
package binarysearch;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Binarysearch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("quotes.txt"));

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    String str = null;

    //Getting all of the input from the textfile
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(str); //Getting all of the lines of the textfile
    }

    String array[] = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);

    String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What quote number would you like to see? (1 - 99)");
    System.out.println("Searching: " + num  + "  "+ binarySearch(array, 0, array.length - 1, num));
}

public static boolean binarySearch(String myArray[], int left,
        int right, String num) {
    //Temporary print for learning purposes
    System.out.print("Searching array: ");
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + myArray[i] + "]");
    }
    System.out.println(" for " + num);
    //end temporary print

    int middle;
    if (left > right) {
        return false;
    }
    middle = (left + right) / 2;
    if (myArray[middle].equals(num)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (num.compareTo(myArray[middle]) > 0) {
        return binarySearch(myArray, left, middle - 1,
                num);
    } else {
        return binarySearch(myArray, middle + 1, right,
                num);
    }
}
}
```

The text file I have:

```
1
quote 1
2
quote 2
4
quote 3
7
quote 4
8
quote 5
12
quote 6
16
quote 7
18
quote 8
22
quote 9
23
quote 10
```

Comment: "...it seems to not be working" Describe in what way(s) it is not working.

Comment: I have the first part working where I'm getting the input into an array but i'm currently trying to see if the quote number exists and if it does the print the quote in a JOptionPane. If the quote number doesn't exist then output that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would make the array an array of objects each of which contains an ID and QuoteString; then the b-search operates on the ID property of each object in the array.

Comment: What you have makes no sense.  You apparently have alternating quote numbers and quotes in adjacent array entries, meaning that quite often you'll examine the entry corresponding to the quote rather the quote number.  If you maintain that scheme you should make your index values be half what they are, then multiply the index by 2 to access the quote number and multiply by 2 and add one to get the quote itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting false because when it checks to see whether or not the user's number is above or below the median, it sometimes lands in the index of the actually quote. The index will be on the quote number or the actual quote depending on the number entered, so you'll get false, even though it exists. You can either create a new array in your method containing only the quote numbers, or alter it to ignore the odd indexes which contain your quotes.